# Popup window android with alpha back view

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog

how is posible to do it, I actually have this code:

```
public void openDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); // Context, this, etc.
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wrongpass_reg);
    dialog.setTitle("cualquier cosa");
    dialog.show();
}
```

I need to put the the back screen with alpha, making it almost transparent as in this image:

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eps12.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a full screen dialog set it with a custom theme.

create a full screen dialog and set its content with inside padding.
something like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#cb000000"
   android:padding="20dp">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       ....
       ....
       YOUR CONTENT
       ....
       ..../>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The custom theme should be something like this one:

```
<style name="Dialog_Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

finally, set it to the dialog, like this:

```
final dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: Dont work, maybe I did a mistake...I added the last line into: final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this, R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wrongpass_reg);
        dialog.setTitle("Wrong pass");
        dialog.show();

Comment: the theme is only for fullscreen.. the trick is in the layout with the padding.
your layout looks like my example?